# how to send data-id to another page

Tags: javascript, php, html

im trying to send the id of the product selected in portfolio.php page to the page portfolio-detail.php and display the information from database according to the selected id

this is portfolio.php page

```
      <ul class="portfolio-area da-thumbs">
        <?php foreach ($product as $value): ?>

        <li class="portfolio-item" data-id="id-0" data-type="web">
          <div class="span3">

            <div class="thumbnail">
              <div class="image-wrapp">
                <img src="<?php echo $target_dir.'/'.$value['product_pic'];  ?>" alt="Portfolio name" title="" />
                <article class="da-animate da-slideFromRight">
                  <a class="zoom" data-pretty="prettyPhoto" href="<?php echo $target_dir.'/'.$value['product_pic'];  ?>">
                        <i class="icon-zoom-in icon-rounded icon-48 active"></i>
                        </a>
                  <a href="portfolio-detail.php" data-id="<?=$value['id']; ?>">
                        <i class="icon-link icon-rounded icon-48 active"></i>
                        </a>
                  <div class="hidden-tablet">
                    <p>
                      <?php echo $value['product_name']; ?>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </article>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>

        </li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>

      </ul>
```

and this is portfolio-detail.php page

```
<section id="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="span12">
        <article>
          <div class="heading">
            <h4><?php echo $product['product_name']; ?></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix">
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="span8">
              <!-- start flexslider -->
              <div class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
                  <li>
                    <img src="<?php echo $target_dir.'/'.$product['product_pic'];  ?>" alt="" />
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <!-- end flexslider -->
              <p>
                <?php echo $product['product_desc']; ?>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
              <aside>
                <div class="widget">
                  <div class="project-widget">
                    <h4 class="rheading">Portfolio detail<span></span></h4>
                    <ul class="project-detail">
                      <li><label>Project name :</label> <?php echo $product['product_name']; ?></li>
                      <li><label>Category :</label> <?php echo $product['product_code']; ?></li>
                      <li><label>Project date :</label> 12 Apr 2013</li>
                      <li><label>Project link :</label><a href="#">www.somelink.com</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </aside>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
        <!-- end article full post -->
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

how to show the details of a product according to the one selected ?

Comment: Just pass it along as a GET parameter in the URL …?

Comment: AJAX maybe?????

Comment: @Jay Blanchard how to use ajax for that ? :)

Comment: AJAX isn't needed since this is a different page. @misorude is right by using `$_GET`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

In **portfolio.php**

Change:

```
<a href="portfolio-detail.php" data-id="<?=$value['id']; ?>">
```

To:

```
<a href="portfolio-detail.php?data-id=<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">
```

Top of **portfolio-detail.php** add:

```
$id = $_GET['data-id'];
```

Do your DB query with `$id`

```
$product = {db stuff here};
```

Of course all proper validation will need to get added.